# Google Local Search and Markers

Tags: google-local-search

I'm following the code located at this page:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#localsearch_with_markers

the search the demo shows is:

```
 // Execute an initial search
 searchControl.execute('pizza');
```

How can I get it to search more than one term?  For example something equivalent to:

```
 // Execute an initial search
 searchControl.execute('pizza');
 searchControl.execute('coffee');
```

This method will only return the 'coffee' results.  It completely ignores 'pizza'.

From reviewing this demo it appears to be possible...
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#the_hello_world_of_local_search

if you look at the following code:

```
  // Specify search quer(ies)
 localSearch.execute('coffee New York NY');
```

and change it to:

```
  // Specify search quer(ies)
 localSearch.execute('pizza');
 localSearch.execute('coffee');
```

It will return both pizza and coffe results.  Any ideas to get this to show up on the map though?